# How does the web browser know if the url being requested is https or http

Tags: web-services, sockets, http, url, https

---

When I type google.com (note, I didn't specify it's http or https.)in the chrome, the chrome automatically goes to https://google.com, which is a secured socket connection that connect to port 443. So, my question is how does my browser know it should connect to 443 instead of 80? Or, to put it more simply, how does my browser know google.com use secured socket for http?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP procotocol!

Chrome by default appends **http://** prefix, and sends the http://google.com request to the HTTP port:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
...
```

Then google.com replies:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://google.com
...
```

Notice the **https** in the Location header.

Then Chrome automatically handles redirections, and sends the second request to the HTTPS port.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
...
```

Which finally replies with the content displayed in the browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
....
```

Comment: This is really a detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The browser *usually* tries HTTP first, then gets a redirect to HTTPS. That's the *common* case, but not the only one. Chrome and Firefox support the notion of `HTTP Strict Transport Security Preload Lists` which are lists of sites which should only be contacted via HTTPS, even if referenced with a HTTP URL.

You can learn more about HSTS [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/08/18/hsts-strict-transport-security-attacks-mitigations-deployment-https.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

its not your browser doing it but google redirecting http://www.google.com to https://www.google.com.